# Hide directory contents from showing when accessing the URL directly

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, directory-listing, rewrite

On my site, if you browse to `http://example.com/images/` the contents of the entire directory are shown like so:

[image: Need to prevent this from showing]

How can I make it so that this doesn't happen?

Can I create an `.htaccess` file in that directory? Or is there a better way? I really want to block directory listing for the entire site (i.e. every directory on that site).

I figure it's either something that has to be done in Apache or using an global `.htaccess` file and placing it in the `public_html` folder, perhaps?

**EDIT**

I diverted this using an `index.php` file, but I still feel that security is an issue here, how can I fix this permanently?

Comment: OMG, I'm a retard, just changed the permissions from 755 to 751.  Is that secure?  751?  Should I use something different instead?

Answer (score 5):

Depending on how your `<directory>` directives are defined, you have a couple of options.

For that directory, `Options -Indexes` will turn that off. This can be done anywhere in the httpd.conf file to disable that sort of thing.

Also, in an .htaccess file in that specific directory you can place `IndexIgnore *` will still produce the list but hide all the contents. A bit hacky, but if you can't modify httpd.conf can work in a pinch.

Comment: Where is the httpd.conf file located?  I see a lot of files in my root like this:  `.bash_logout`, `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, `.contactemail`, `.dns`, `.ftpquota`, `.lastlogin`, and `cpbackup-exclude.conf` do I just create the httpd.conf file?

Comment: @Sologhost It varies by distro, but is frequently found in /etc/http, or /etc/apache. I sense a shared-hosting account, so you may not be able to edit it.

Comment: Yeah, I believe I am on a shared hosting.  So there is no way to do this I suppose.  But I do see an `/etc/` folder.  Just nothing in there but an `ftpquota` file.

Comment: .htaccess is your best bet, then. Try an `Options -Indexes` first, then if that doesn't work, try IndexIgnore.

Answer (score 3):

You need to disable directory browsing. You can do that for the whole server by modifying `httpd.conf`, or you can do it in a directory of your choice by using a `.htaccess` file.

In both cases, look for the line that begins with `Options` and some other words; if it contains `Indexes`, change it to `-Indexes`; if it doesn't contain it, add it to the line.

If there is no `Options` directive, just add `Options -Indexes`, and that's all.

Comment: OK, thanks.  The httpd.conf file did NOT exist, so I created it and, on the first line added this:  `Options -Indexes` and uploaded it to the public_html directory and TADA, it is working nicely I think.  Cheers :)  Is that all that should be added to the `httpd.conf` file?

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work... arggg.

Comment: httpd.conf is located in /etc (or /etc/httpd/, or something similar) and is Apache's global configuration file, it *must* exist or your web server would not be working at all. .htaccess needs instead to be created in the directory where you want to change settings.

Comment: Well, I can see the /etc/ directory, but all that is in there is a file `ftpquota`

Comment: Ok, well, I diverted this using an index.php file, but I still feel that security is an issue here, how can I fix this PERMANENTLY!

Comment: Use a .htaccess file in your site's root.